# How to automatically close the process that is started by application, when application closes in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am getting wired problem with a process that is started by my c# application,in my application i start a process that runs a ffmpeg command which executes well but when in any how if i closes my application then that process still continues to executes.

```
    private static bool RunRecordProcess(string command)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        try
        {                
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new 
            ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + 
            FFMPEG_EXE_FILE_PATH);
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.Arguments = "-hide_banner -loglevel 8 " + 
            command;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.Verb = "";

            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();               
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            if (error.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    //throw new Exception("Failure some error occured");
                }
            }
            process.WaitForExit();
        }   
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            process.Kill();
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(ex);
            return false;
        }         
        return true;
    }
```

What i want is when my application exits my process that is started by the application will automatically exit so that no useless process will be using my system Cpu.

Thankyou!

Comment: Than have a look at `ApplicationExit` event MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit?view=netframework-4.8) This example is almost about your requirements

Comment: You have declared your Process (`Process process = new Process();`) inside the method (`RunRecordProcess`). Declared it as a Field, so you can then access the `process` object from the FormClosing/FormClosed event, verify if it's still running and terminate it when you need to. Btw, you are redirecting StdIn and StdOut but you're not using them. `EnableRaisingEvents` is only used to raise the `Exited` event.

Answer (score 0):

You should create job object (CreateJobObject function in kernel32). There is more description:

https://tulisanlain.blogspot.com/2016/08/kill-child-process-when-parent-exit-c.html